# How to make bootstrap icon display inline with text in a tag?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap navigation pill that shows text and an arrow. Unfortunately if the text is to long the arrow appears on the border of the anchor. Html looks like this.

```
        <a href="#">
          <span> Some longer sample text</span>
          <i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
```

Demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyrisu/FNcGX/

How can I display it inline with the block of text (text can/should wrap)?

Comment: Not working float:right perfectly - This is the issue right?

Comment: Float right worked OK - just the icon was displayed partly outside of the a tag border (but it was on the right side of the tag).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your text can wrap as you said then this can work..

```
<span><i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right"></i>Some longer sample text</span>
```

**Update**:

```
<span class="iwt">
<span>Some longer sample text</span>
<i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right"></i>
</span>

.iwt{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: why use `class="iwt"` when you can replace `span` tag with `div` tag ?

Answer (score 3):

Please use this structure

```
<a href="#">
       <i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right"></i>
      <span> Some longer sample text</span>

    </a>
```

Please demo http://jsfiddle.net/FNcGX/9/

Answer (score 0):

Using css white-space:nowrap; solves text in one line issue.

```
.subject-pill > a {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
 .subject-pill{ 
    width: 218px;
 }
```

reference site :
[white space no wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: Sorry - I was probably not clear (English is not my first language). Text is fine (it doesn't need to be in one line). I just need the icon to be on the right of the block of text (doesn't matter if the text is wrapped or not).

Comment: or you can try adding this :

.subject-pill{
  width: 218px;
}

or remove display:inline-block; from 

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] class in bootstrap.min.css