# Datatables: Issue with font-awesome icon in header being displayed on new line

Tags: datatables, twig, font-awesome

I am creating an admin view into user details on a website. From that view I want the admin to be able to edit certain columns from certain tables, but not all columns. To indicate which columns are editable I am using a font-awesome icon to show that column is editable. JS will be applied to then allow the admin to do any editing. However, I'm stuck with the formatting simply not working as expected. It keeps showing the icon on a new line creating the ugly table as shown here:

[image]

**HTML**
I have tried several ways to load the table so it will be rendered properly but nothing I have tried has worked. The HTML is loaded through a twig which is received from an AJAX call:

```
<table class="user-members-data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for key in user_details|keys %}
                <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for value in user_details %}
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**
On return the Datatable is initialised but before initialisation the edit icons are added to the relevant column titles. The editable columns are returned as a separate json_encoded array which is checked against (`jquery_data.editable_columns`):

```
$( 'table.user-members-data thead th' ).each( function(){
    var header = $( this ).html()

    if( jQuery.inArray( header, response.jquery_data.editable_columns ) !== -1 ){
        $( this ).html( header + ' <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" edit="' + header + '"></i>' )
    }
})
$( 'table.user-members-data' ).DataTable( {
    'scrollX'  : true,
    'ordering' : false,
    'paging'   : false,
    'info'     : false,
    'searching': false
} )
```

**Load icon through HTML**
Alternatively I have tweaked the twig to include the edit icon and to load the Datatable without jQuery adding the icons:

```
{% for key in user_details.table|keys %}
    <th>
        {{ key }}
        {% if key in user_details.editable_columns %}
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" edit="{{ key }}"></i>
        {% endif %}
    </th>
{% endfor %}
```

This resulted in the exact same issue with the new lines.

**columns.adjust()**
Elsewhere I have seen advice to use this after the draw of the Datatables to fix any width issues. This has not worked for me either.

It feels as if Datatable is simply not seeing the icon at all when setting the width of the column?

Comment: Have you tried using a `<span>` with `display:block`? See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948716/how-to-make-bootstrap-icon-display-inline-with-text-in-a-tag). Or for more control, try a [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) in each cell?

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you ever so much! That has worked a treat. Setting the title within a span with display:block; and white-space:nowrap; has sorted the issue perfectly. If you want to add that as an answer I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it worked! You refined my guess with `white-space:nowrap` - so the answer is yours to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to andrewjames for pointing the way in the comments.

The solution came by wrapping the title in a span with `display:block;` and `white-space:no-wrap;` added as styling.

```
$( 'table.user-members-data thead th' ).each( function(){
    var header = $( this ).html()

    if( jQuery.inArray( header, response.jquery_data.editable_columns ) !== -1 ){
        $( this ).html( '<span style="display:block; white-space:nowrap;">' + header + ' <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" edit="' + header + '"></i></span>' )
    }
})
```